# Find to which array element this text belong

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Basically I have an array of sentences like:

```
[
  'Hi I am Mark. I love plains!', 
  'Some of  my friends , like football. 5- 3 =2. R-a-ndom syntaxx.. And I\'m too', 
  'Mark is a great guy! We love him'
]
```

And raw text `array.join('')`:

```
Hi I am Mark. I love plains! Some  of my ...
```

The program shows every word from text to user for 1 second and after show then next word.

Like:  `Hi`..1 sec and replace with ..`I`.. 1 sec and replace with..`am`..1 sec..etc., 1 word - 1 sec to read.

User can finish reading on any word.

What I have: An array of sentences, `wordIndex` - the index of word in text on which he finished reading, `rawText` - the whole text without array.

What I try to do is to find index in array of sentences on which he finished reading.

Example: He finished on word `plains` it's `[6]` (wordIndex) in raw text and `[0]` index (that index I need to find)  in array of sentences.

Also, the text can be very big (the whole book), and I need a solution that is also well optimized. Thanks!

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Why do you put those in an array if you display it word for word?

Comment: @FrankerZ: `What I try to do is to find index in array on which he finished reading.` Sounds pretty specific to me.

Comment: Do not see you trying, see you asking for code.

Comment: You may want to check out the docs for `arr.indexOf`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @Hector: Wont help him much since a word could be in multiple parts of the array. Like `I` or `Mark`.

Comment: Doesn't the loop that's displaying the words know which array element it got the word from?

Comment: How do you know which `Mark` the user stopped on?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array of sentences and figure out how many words are in each line. Add them together until you reach your word index.

```
var words = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++)
{
    words += sentences[i].split(" ").length;
    if(words > wordIndex)
        return i;
}
```

This will return the index of the sentence that the word is from.

*Note `words > wordIndex` because your wordIndex is zero-indexed, and the length of the arrays will return a value that is not.*

Comment: Good solution, I'll try it out